# After Upgrading to Specflow3 and Deveroom Go To Definition not working for Steps in Feature

Tags: specflow, visual-studio-2019

Here is my setup:
Specflow 3.0.191
Specflow.tools.MsBuild.Generation 3.0.191
Specflow.NUnit 3.0.191
Visual Studio 2019 Version 16
Deveroom Extension 1.1.1

When I am in a feature file in Visual Studio I am not able to go to the definition of any of my steps. I have tried F12 as well as right clicking on the step and choosing Go To Definition. Neither goes anywhere or pops any kind of error. There is a disconnect that doesn't prohibit the tests from running but does cause the Go To Definition not to work.

I have followed the configuration guide from the Specflow site (https://specflow.org/2019/updating-to-specflow-3/). My tests are running and working. I have deleted the specmap files from the %TEMP% directory and that didn't do anything. I uninstalled/reinstalled the deveroom Visual Studio plugin also which didn't work.

I welcome any insight.

Thanks,
J.R.

Comment: I had to disable the Deveroom Visual Studio extension and enable the Specflow extension for Visual Studio 2019. I have put in an issue with the team working on Deveroom and when it is fixed I will switch back. For now the Specflow extension works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are having the same issue with what I believe the root cause is the Visual Studio Extension version. According to the link you provided it should be supported by Specflow version 2.3.2 or higher, but we are still having issues with 2.4.1

A workaround for us was to uninstall the extension and then install the version appropriate .vsix file for the Visual Studio version below:

https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow.VisualStudio/releases/tag/v2017.2.7

And then remember to un-check automatic updates for this extension

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your response. I am thinking that your issue is because you aren't on the Specflow 3 package. The Visual Studio extension was updated to support the new Specflow package but broke some stuff for those that aren't on it. Upgrading to 3.0 changes some stuff and requires some special steps so I wouldn't do it unless you have some time to work out the kinks.

Comment: Yes unfortunately we are not at a point where we have capacity to refactor the necessary changes to upgrade to Specflow 3 but according to the official documentation this extension update should not have broken support for any Specflow version higher than 2.3.2 so it does feel like there is potentially another issue with the recent extension update to me

Comment: Agreed. It shouldn't have broken the functionality. I am hopeful that the Deveroom extension is fixed and I can go with that one. It is a ground up rewrite of the extension and seems to be the future. It just needs some more work.

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with this for some time.  I found that I had the following in my specflow.json config file:

```
{
    "allowDebugGeneratedFiles": true
},
```

changing this to

```
{
    "allowDebugGeneratedFiles": false
},
```

and rebuilding fixed the issue for me.